# How can I learn LaTeX enough to write a paper?

Tags: tutorials

Recently one of my college teachers had given a problem for which I had developed a solution. He told me to write it down in a technical paper in a website called overleaf.com.

However, I am completely lost. The template of the papers of the website is intimidating and I don't know where to start. I also have no idea what a technical paper is supposed to look like, what kind of language it is supposed to contain, etc. I don't know where to start. Please help me.

Comment: What is the field? Will you need a bibliography? As for the *content* of the paper, that is a different question for a different site. But LaTeX can be fairly easy to learn the basics of ... though this is truer usually for people who are familiar with the idea of a "markup language" such as HTML. For a general introduction to the world of LaTeX, see (e.g.) [*The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX*](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/?lang=en). Maybe [Overleaf itself](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/learn/free-online-introduction-to-latex-part-1#.VfzU4Vvz0fo) can be helpful.

Comment: if you're writing a lot of math, I found it really helpful at the start to practice in the 'ask question' area of the math stack exchange, since you are able to see the output in real time:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

 I used this as a reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: There's also https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php if you just want a sandbox to mess around with maths commands

Comment: Yeah, hanging out in Math Stack Exchange, Overleaf, reading the LaTeX tutorial on Stack exchange helped me learn. Now, I've installed TexMaker and MikiTex too.